# Tell Xcode to ignore a header for some targets?

Tags: xcode, macos, ios, header, target

I have an Xcode project with a mac target and an iOS target.  The project contains a class IPhoneOnlyClass which is used in the iOS target only.  I have unchecked IPhoneOnlyClass.m from the mac target so it doesn't compile that file.

Now IphoneOnlyClass.h contains the line

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
```

When I am compiling for the mac target, Xcode gives me an error:

error: GameKit/GameKit.h: No such file or directory

I could get around this with a #ifdef, but is there a better way?  I'd rather tell Xcode to ignore the header altogether when compiling the mac target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be importing the iPhone-only class headers in your Mac-specific or multi-platform source files in the first place.

If that's unavoidable, then you'll need to use a preprocessor macro, such as TARGET_OS_MAC versus TARGET_OS_IPHONE, to determine when to import the headers for your iPhone-only classes.

Also, make sure you haven't accidentally added any iPhone-only classes to the Compile Sources build phase of your Mac target.

Comment: The .m file is not in the compile sources build phase.  How do I tell Xcode not to look at the header?  I accidentally checked the .m file to include in a previous build, then unchecked it.  Could that be causing the problem?  Other headers, corresponding to .m files that I never put into the target, are not having the same problem.

Comment: The problem was that one of my other .m files imported it, and I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think #ifdef are bad solution. If you look at UIKit header files you will see Apple use a lot of "#if" such as:

```
#if __IPHONE_4_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
```

And

```
#if TARGET_OS_MAC && !(TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
```

(Last line was copied from NSObjCRuntime.h)

Answer (score -1):

you need to add the framework to your Xcode project.

`Frameworks / Linked Frameworks, Add -> Existing Frameworks`

for more detailed info, just google `add framework to xcode`